# Android Webview open local html file with http:// url not file:/// url

Tags: android, url, webview

I have a html file  that needs to run by a webserver to works correctly. so url schema should starts with `"http://"`. I copied this html file in assets folder in android studio and I want to load it in **webview** but I have no idea how to make it as loading from a web server with `http://` url.

I thank you in advance for your helps

Comment: "I have a html file that needs to run by a webserver to works correctly" -- please explain, in greater detail, what you mean by this.

Comment: @CommonsWare, it's a html5 phaser game, in windows for example I run it by wamp server. url needs to start with http not file://.

Comment: "in windows for example I run it by wamp server" -- if the WAMP server is dynamically generating the HTML, you cannot have it in `assets/`, as Android is not a WAMP server. If the HTML is static, then you should not need a WAMP server to use the HTML.

Comment: please check this to see why I need a webserver, http://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started, thanks for your help

Comment: Then perhaps you should talk to the Phaser people about how best to embed a Phaser-based game in an Android app.

Comment: They have a common practice using Apache coedova however I want to load it on webview, so I will have full control on my app by writing native java code and only display the game in webview.